# Delphi Get the handle of a directory

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Using Delphi 07 is it possible to (How do I) get the handle of a directory if I know its path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 API `CreateFile()` function can open a handle to a directory on NT-based versions of Windows (ie, any version other than Win3.x, Win9x, and WinME).